# Rails button_to and using patch vs post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a really hard time getting rails to use the 'button_to' tag with a patch request vs post.

This is my tag:

```
<%= button_to 'Start Game', { :controller => 'provides', :id => @prov_id}, :method => :patch %>
```

I'm using 'resources :provides' in my routes, and I have an update method in my Provide controller.

Here is the output for provides when I run rake routes..

```
    provides GET    /provides(.:format)            provides#index
             POST   /provides(.:format)            provides#create
 new_provide GET    /provides/new(.:format)        provides#new
edit_provide GET    /provides/:id/edit(.:format)   provides#edit
     provide GET    /provides/:id(.:format)        provides#show
             PATCH  /provides/:id(.:format)        provides#update
             PUT    /provides/:id(.:format)        provides#update
             DELETE /provides/:id(.:format)        provides#destroy
```

Everything *should* be working, but I get the below error...

```
Started PATCH "/provides?id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-12 19:20:28 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/provides"):
```

What is going wrong here? This is driving me insane, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't work, I need to specify the provides controller b/c it's going to a different controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a route: `PATCH  /provides/:id(.:format)`, but there is no PATCH route for `"/provides?id=1"`

Try:

`<%= button_to 'Start Game', provide_path(@prov_id), :method => :patch %>`

See more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you need to have a form tag for a PATCH since browsers don't currently generate non AJAX PATCH requests.

So pass `:method => :patch` to `form_for` as follows:

```
<%= form_for @provides, method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :foo, value: 'somevalue' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Start Game' %>
<% end %>
```

This will send a method parameter which rails will detect and your controller can handle as a real PATCH.  I included in the example the ability to pass hidden parameters for the actual patch as its unclear what usefulness PATCH would offer in your example otherwise.

**Note**: Don't try and embed the above html inside another form. The HTML spec doesn't permit nested `form` tags.